# Como exibir o progresso na TaskBar

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá pessoal eu ultimamente vi num fórum que é sim possível mostrar o progresso na Taskbar (compatível com Windows 7)

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace System.Windows.Forms.TaskBar {
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the thumbnail progress bar state.
    /// </summary>
    public enum ThumbnailProgressState {
        /// <summary>
        /// No progress is displayed.
        /// </summary>
        NoProgress = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// The progress is indeterminate (marquee).
        /// </summary>
        Indeterminate = 0x1,
        /// <summary>
        /// Normal progress is displayed.
        /// </summary>
        Normal = 0x2,
        /// <summary>
        /// An error occurred (red).
        /// </summary>
        Error = 0x4,
        /// <summary>
        /// The operation is paused (yellow).
        /// </summary>
        Paused = 0x8
    }

    [ComImportAttribute()]
    [GuidAttribute("ea1afb91-9e28-4b86-90e9-9e9f8a5eefaf")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface ITaskbarList3 {
        // ITaskbarList
        [PreserveSig]
        void HrInit();
        [PreserveSig]
        void AddTab(IntPtr hwnd);
        [PreserveSig]
        void DeleteTab(IntPtr hwnd);
        [PreserveSig]
        void ActivateTab(IntPtr hwnd);
        [PreserveSig]
        void SetActiveAlt(IntPtr hwnd);

        // ITaskbarList2
        [PreserveSig]
        void MarkFullscreenWindow(
        IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fFullscreen);

        // ITaskbarList3
        void SetProgressValue(IntPtr hwnd, UInt64 ullCompleted, UInt64 ullTotal);
        void SetProgressState(IntPtr hwnd, ThumbnailProgressState tbpFlags);
    }

    [GuidAttribute("56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090")]
    [ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComImportAttribute()]
    internal class CTaskbarList {}
}
```

Como posso usa-lo?

Comment: O que você quer dizer por "mostrar uma barra de progresso na taskbar"? Você quer criar uma barar de progresso em uma aplicação windows?

Comment: Acredito que ele tá falando de usar o ícone da aplicação na barra de tarefas do Windows, que é grande e transparente, como barra de progresso. Como uma janela de transferência de arquivos (download ou cópia) faz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei a solução para este código:

```
void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var taskbar = ((ITaskBarList3) CTaskBarList);
    taskbar.HrInit();
    taskbar.SetProgressState(ThumbnailProgessState.Normal);
    taskbar.SetProgressValue(this.Handle, 50, 0); //Handle é do Form
}
```

E assim o progresso será mostrado na *TaskBar*. Compatível com o Windows 7 e 8: